# Passing data from java file to ajax

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp

I have a java class printing the progress of a process as 1%, 2%, 3%. Now I want to read this progress using AJAX requests and continuously update the progress in the webpage. I cannot convert the java file into a servlet as it is being used as an scriptlet by Jasper.

Scriptlet code is :

```
public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException{
     count = (Integer) this.getVariableValue("count"); 
     out.println(count);
     Thread.sleep(200); 
}
```

How can I read the data printed by java from an AJAX request?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you think about your choice to not show the code you have that's doing the stuff you just described, while also asking for help about just these things?

Comment: what is your java class running inside? Tomcat or similar?

Comment: @williamburnham yes it is running inside tomcat

Comment: @kumasena done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your scriptlet created? The only thing that comes to mind is if you've got a class like

```
public class YourScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

You can add a constructor and private member for another object that serves as a container for whatever you need outside of the Jasper context, like so

Some object to keep track of the count (or whatever it is you need to keep track of)

```
public class YourInfoObject {
    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger();
    public int increment() {
        return this.count.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public int get() {
        return this.count.intValue();
    }
    public void set(int value) {
        this.count.set(value);
    }
}
```

Your scriptlet class with a constructor

```
public class YourScriptlet extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
    private final YourInfoObject obj;
    public YourScriptlet(YourInfoObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public void afterDetailEval() throws JRScriptletException {
        // your code here
        obj.set(count);
    }
}
```

Then, from wherever else (a Servlet with a reference to your object) you can access the value.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer!